# Parsing attributes in Dataflow SQL

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

Given a Pub/Sub topic, BigQuery enables streaming data to a table using [Dataflow SQL](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/samples/join-streaming-data-with-sql) syntax.

Let's say you post this message `{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}` to a topic. In BigQuery, with the Dataflow engine, you would need to define the `my_topic` schema as

**Step1**

```
event_timestamp: TIMESTAMP
a: INT64
b: INT64
c: INT64
```

And then creating a Dataflow streaming job using that command, so that it streams every message to a destination BigQuery table.

**Step2**

```
gcloud dataflow sql query 'SELECT * FROM pubsub.topic.my_project.my_topic' \
  --job-name my_job --region europe-west1 --bigquery-write-disposition write-append \
  --bigquery-project my_project --bigquery-dataset staging --bigquery-table my_topic

gcloud pubsub topics publish my_topic --message='{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}'
​
bq query --nouse_legacy_sql \
  'SELECT * FROM my_project.staging.my_topic ORDER BY event_timestamp DESC LIMIT 10'

+---------------------+-----+-----+-----+
|   event_timestamp   |  a  |  b  |  c  |
+---------------------+-----+-----+-----+
| 2020-10-28 14:21:40 |  1  |  2  |  3  |
```

At **Step 2** I would like to send also `--attribute="origin=gcloud,username=gcp"` to the Pub/Sub topic. Is is possible to define the schema at **Step 1** so that it writes to the table automatically?

I have been trying different things:

- `attributes: STRUCT` in the schema, following [this Beam extensions documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/sql/extensions/create-external-table/#pubsub), but all I get is JSON parsing errors in Dataflow
- `gcloud pubsub topics publish my_topic --message='{"a": 1, "b": 2}' --attribute='c=3'` expecting the message to be flattened as in this [piece of code](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/b26b499ca53349c72bd3ebf5b99fd41ef22a986e/sdks/java/extensions/sql/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/meta/provider/pubsub/PubsubTableProviderTest.java#L48-L50), but I get a `NULL` value for `c` in the resulting table.

Thank you.

Comment: I can't achieve the same thing. It's maybe impossible!!

Comment: The only way to achieve same behavior seems to use a `WHERE` sql statement from the topic schema to filter messages at in the Dataflow job.
Dataflow SQL misses the possibility to filter attributes like in subscriptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pub/Sub attributes are of `MAP` type, but that is not one of Dataflow SQL's [supported types](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types). There were discussions about adding support, but I don't know the status of that.

If attributes are important, I suggest creating a custom pipeline using [ReadFromPubSub](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.23.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub.ReadFromPubSub)

Comment: I think the 
"Pub/Sub to BigQuery" Dataflow template can help too, it uses the PubsubIO class.  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/a31f7bed8883435442e88df53288efd2fd5a091e/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubSubToBigQuery.java#L241-L253